# Best way to store image in database in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Can any one guide which will be the best way to store images to the database? I am using Sql server 2008. Currently I am storing file path in database but when I am trying to fetch it, it is not fetched.

Here is code to save image:

```
string Extention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuBanner.FileName);
if (Extention == ".jpg" || Extention == ".jpeg" || Extention == ".bmp" || Extention == ".PNG")
 {
    result.Banner_SignUp_Page = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuBanner.FileName);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    lblMsg.Visible = true;
    Response.Redirect("ListOfEvent.aspx");
    //lblMsg.Text = "Records updated successfully.";
 }
```

And code for fetching the image:

```
var result1 = from a in db.EMR_INVITATIONs
    join b in db.EMR_EVENTs on a.EventID equals b.EventID
    where b.EventID == (int)Session["eventid"]   
        select new
                 {
                    Banner = b.Banner_SignUp_Page,
                    Title = b.Title  
                 };
```

Comment: it is not fetched means?? can you post the code?

Comment: Ok please wait i m posting code

Comment: also see if http://debugmode.net/2010/05/10/inserting-and-retrieving-image-using-linq-to-sql-from-asp-net-application/ this link is helpful

Comment: @Monika , I am not sure about case sensitive about image extension i.e. ".jpg" and ".JPG" are same or not, but give it a try to **ToLower()** function. May be it can help you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case:

Below is possible code for what you want to achieve:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    if (fuFileUploader.HasFile && fuFileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string path_file_name = fuFileUploader.PostedFile.FileName;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(path_file_name).Replace(".", "");
        string file_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path_file_name);
        string file_title = txtFileTitle.Text.Trim();
        HelperDataClassesDataContext db = new HelperDataClassesDataContext();

        try
        {
            byte[] file_byte = fuFileUploader.FileBytes;
            Linq.Binary file_binary = new Linq.Binary(file_byte);

            ControlDocument cd = new ControlDocument
            {
                guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                file_ext = ext,
                file_nm = file_name.Trim(),
                file_title=file_title,
                file_bin = file_binary,
                is_active = true,
                upload_page_type = rblLocation.SelectedValue,
                upload_dt = DateTime.Now,
                upload_by = UtilUniverse.Common.CurrentUserLogin.Trim()
            };

            db.ControlDocuments.InsertOnSubmit(cd);
        }
        finally
        {

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

A code to resize before saving image to disk. It save path in database only not image in database. If we save path in database and files on disk, then **we can save CPU cost** each time when we have to display that image , (give it a try). You can use it for saving any image of your project, just provide the uploader control and image path to it.

```
public static bool SaveImage(HttpPostedFile imageUpload, string imagePath, out string error)
{
    error = "";
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageUpload.FileName);
    if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".png")
    {
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap objImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageUpload.InputStream);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap outImage = new Bitmap(170, 200);
            System.Drawing.Graphics outGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(outImage);
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            outGraphics.FillRectangle(sb, 0, 0, 170, 200);
            outGraphics.DrawImage(objImage, 0, 0, 170, 200);
            sb.Dispose();
            outGraphics.Dispose();
            objImage.Dispose();
            outImage.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = "Failed to save Image. Error: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error = "Invalid image foramt.";
    }
    return false;
}
```

then you can simply fetch it by getting image path.
i.e.
image.url = //image column value

Comment: this does not saves image in DB as user wanted

Comment: yes, it does not save image in database but it save image in disk and path to database, although user dont want it, but through this user may be think about the benifit of saving path in database and image on disk.

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S., edited in my answer :)

Comment: @Sohail i respect ur suggetion and is also correct way to do..but user hasnt asked problem regarding this, thats what i was trying to point out

Comment: F.R.I.E.N.D.S.,  I agree with you bro, I just want to user to try and   do it other way, cause i learn this spending whole week. May be after trying this, user can save it resources. 
@Monika, I am agree with FRIENDS, My solution is not upto your problem I post my solution so that you can try various solutions and do the way which fits you best. :)

Comment: @Sohail no problem bro, your solution can be helpful to someone who is trying to save images on disk(as suggested by you.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 InstituteRegistration insti = new InstituteRegistration(); 
 if (FileUploadInstituteImage.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            string extension =         System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadInstituteImage.FileName);
            if (extention.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extention.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extention.ToLower() == ".gif" || extention.ToLower() == ".png" || extention.ToLower() == ".bmp" || extention.ToLower() == ".tif" || extention.ToLower() == ".tiff")
            {
                Stream fsInstitute = FileUploadInstituteImage.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader brInsti = new BinaryReader(fsInstitute);
                Byte[] bytesInstitute = brInsti.ReadBytes((Int32)fsInstitute.Length);
                insti.InstituteImage = bytesInstitute;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Invalid File.";
                return;
            }
        }

 db.InstituteRegistrations.InsertOnSubmit(insti);
 db.SubmitChanges();
```